# dropzone passing null file name

Tags: php, laravel

**Dropzone.js** not passing the file name:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="jumbotron">Laravel Multiple Images Upload Using Dropzone</h3>
  <form method="post" action="{{url('image/upload/store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
    @csrf
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your controller code where are you getting `NULL`?

Comment: $image = $request->file('file');
    $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path('images'),$imageName);

Comment: getClientOrginalName() thorw an error null

Comment: @MuhammadImran check if `$image` is an array, if you're uploading multiple file `$image` should be an array of files

Comment: yes dropzone.js uploading multiple images

Comment: but am uploading only one image

Comment: $image is an array Nehal Sir